# Is it possible to refresh the inCall screen?

Tags: android

I have an application which listens incoming calls. The application has a database with a its own contact names and numbers.

When you get an incoming call, if the incoming number(say,1234) is not available in native contact database, the application checks it in it's database and finds the contact name from the database if number is available in it. (say, xyz)...

My aim is to refresh the incall screen with new contact name saying "xyz calling.." instead of "1234 calling.."..

Is it possible??..

Comment: Take a look at a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2385685/1321873), the answer to which is applicable in your case as well

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for the response. But I don't want to replace the inCall screen.. My aim was to jus refresh the incall screen with the updated contact name.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to refresh Incoming call screen but u can display desired name by fetching your own database... For that u need run ur own thread on incoming call screen, I used Timer and Timer Task to do so here is example

Your BroadcastReceiver should contain

```
ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        incomingNumber = extras.getString("incoming_number");
if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

/********** Fetch name from your DB ************/

if (Name not present in your DB) 
{
return;
}

if(present){

incomingCallTimer = new Timer();
ToastMessageHandler messageHandler = new ToastMessageHandler(context, contactName);                 
incomingCallTimer.schedule(new ToastTimer(messageHandler), 1000, 2000);

 }
}

if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            // callActionHandler.removeCallbacks(runRingingActivity);
            // setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            try{
            incomingCallTimer.cancel();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
}

class ToastTimer extends TimerTask {

    ToastMessageHandler messageHandler;

    public ToastTimer(ToastMessageHandler messageHandler) {
        this.messageHandler = messageHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Message message = Message.obtain(messageHandler);
        messageHandler.sendMessage(message);



    }

   }
}
```

Toast Handler class

```
public class ToastMessageHandler extends Handler{

Context context;
String message;

public ToastMessageHandler(Context _context , String _message){
    this.context = _context;
    this.message = _message;

}
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    Toast.makeText(msg);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. As you mentioned the only option in my situation is to have a Toast. I couldn't find any way to refresh the incall scree.

Comment: Please share if you got a better solution .

Comment: @Preetha Or U can create Your own incoming call Activty using ITelephony class, for that u need to add .jar framework_intermediates-classes-full-debug.jar

Comment: Thank you very much. DO you have any link on how to do it. If you have pls share. Thanks again

Comment: @Preetha I googeled for ITelephony got that jar, don't have link sorry.. You to search

Comment: Thank you. I saw that in android 2.3 MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission is not allowed for user apps. Then How did you handle this